# Refresh Kendo UI grid on dropdown selected index change event

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Sorry to ask this common question again, but I am really not able to understand a few points.
So, I have this grid which I have generated using Telerik Kendo UI. It's a very simple grid and I have this combo box on the page, which is outside the grid as an independent control. Of course, again this is a Telerik Kendo UI ComboBox control.
Now, I am trying to implement a scenario where when the user changes the selection on Combobox, I want to pass the selection value to the action method and refresh the grid accordingly.
I referred to few articles on StackOverflow and I found these useful links,

[Kendo UI Grid Refesh on Dropdown Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462541/kendo-ui-grid-refesh-on-dropdown-selection)

[How to refresh the Kendo UI grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471046/kendo-ui-grid-refresh)

[Reloading/refreshing Kendo Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399805/reloading-refreshing-kendo-grid)

All these links have provided this code line which will refresh grid on the client side,

```
var grid = $("#Product").data("**kendoGrid**");
grid.dataSource.read();
```

*Now what I am unable to understand is what this above bold word 'kendoGrid' stands for i.e. what should be the parameter for the 'data' method?*

I have implemented the below piece of code for my application but unfortunately, it's not working. *Can anyone please point out what am I missing and how can I fix this code to get it working,*

```
@(Html.Kendo()
        .DropDownList()
        .Name("ddlProject")
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .DataSource(source =>
         {
              source.Read(read => { read.Action("GetProjectsForCurrentUser", "Home"); });
         })
         .OptionLabel("Select a Project")
         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px;height:20px;" })
                                  .Events(e => e.Change("selectedIndexChanged")))

@Html.Action("LoadDefects")

@(Html.Kendo()
      .Grid(Model)
      .Name("DefectGrid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(d => d.DefectId).Title("ID").Width("5%");
          columns.Bound(d => d.Title).Title("Title").Width("20%");
          columns.Bound(d => d.Severity).Title("Severity").Width("10%");
          columns.Bound(d => d.Status).Title("Status").Width("10%");
          columns.Bound(d => d.Description).Title("Description").Width("20%");
          columns.Bound(d => d.LoggedBy).Title("LoggedBy").Width("10%");
          columns.Bound(d => d.LoggedOn).Title("LoggedOn").Width("10%");
      })
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable()
      .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(200))
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                          .Ajax()
                                          .Read(read => read.Action("LoadDefects", "Home").Data("refreshGrid"))
                                          .PageSize(20)
                                          .ServerOperation(false))


var dataItem;

function refreshGrid() {
    return {
        selectedProject: dataItem
    };
}

function selectedIndexChanged(e) {
    dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    alert(grid);
    grid.dataSource.read();
    return;
}

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult LoadDefects(string selectedProject = "")
    {
        var defectList = dBO.GetDefects(2, "2").ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            defectList.Add(defectList[0]);
        }
        return PartialView(defectList);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the `id` of your Kendo UI Grid is `DefectGrid` so you should use:

```
var grid = $("#DefectGrid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.read();
```

You should not modify `kendoGrid` since the Widget that you want to update is a *kendoGrid*.

- If you want to access a Kendo ListView you should do: `$("#elem_id").data("kendoListView");` (being `elem_id` the `id` of the HTML element that includes the ListView).
- If it is a DropDown List, then you should do `$("#elem_id").data("kendoDropDownList");`
- and so on...

When KendoUI creates a Widget, it stores a reference to the *object* that holds the methods and private data to that Widget in `data`. This is something not specific of KendoUI but inherited from `jQuery` (see documentation about jQuery `data` [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)).

Comment: I made the changes, but it didn't work. The grid still does not refresh on drop down selection change event

Answer (score 0):

your Grid read event:

```
 .Read(read => read.Action("My_Read", "Admin").Data("combodata"))
```

your change event function:

```
function selectedIndexChanged() {
                var grid = $("#DefectGrid").data("kendoGrid");

                grid.dataSource.read(); // rebind the Grid's DataSource
            }
```

And add this function

```
 function combodata(e) {

                var value = $("#ddlProject").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
                return { ID: value };
                }
```

**Edit** :
Don't forget reading id in controller

```
 public ActionResult my_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,int ID)
```